# Is the given complex series convergent or divergent? Give a reason. Show work.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{n^2 - i}$$

I'm told to compare this to $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$
but not sure what this means

I know the magnitude of the denominator is $\left | n^4 + 1\right |$ but not sure how this helps me. If I take the magnitude and compare it to $\frac{1}{n^2}$, how does this help me? Since $\frac{i^n}{n^4 + 1}$ is smaller than $\frac{1}{n^2}$ I guess our series converges too?

When we take the magnitude like this... why does this work? What are we doing when we take the magnitude of the denominator?

Comment: absolutely convergent series are convergent and also the fact that $|i^n| = |i|^n =1$, you should fix the starting value.

Comment: How do you know it is abs convergent? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *asymptotic analysis*, this series is absolutely convergent since
$$\biggl|\frac{i^n}{n^2-i}\biggl|=\frac 1{|n^2-i|}=\frac1{\sqrt{n^4+1}}\sim_\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n^4}}=\frac1{n^2}.$$

Comment: (+1) Forget the $\sim$, just use $\lt$

Comment: @robjohn: I agree that here it's not really necessary, but I think that most of the time, it's a safe habit to use asymptotic equivalents, as it makes things much shorter.

Comment: Why do we take the magnitude or the modulus? What's the reasoning behind it? Isn't it weird to take the modulus... aren't we transforming the value into real numbers now?

Comment: Is the infinity sign a typo?

Comment: And why does 1/n^2 converge? What's the simplest proof of that?

Comment: Not at all: `\sim_\infty$  means ‘asymptotically equivalent to’. For your other question, I use the theorem that an absolutely convergent series (i.e. with a convergent  series of absolute values (or moduli for a series of complex numbers)) is itself convergent.

Comment: $\sum 1/n^2$ converges because  of the basic result that a Riemann $p$-series $\sum \frac1{n^\alpha}$ converges if and only if $\alpha>1$ (by the integral test).

Comment: @Jwan622: look up [Absolute Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence). If a series converges absolutely, it converges. Note that $\frac1{k^2}\le\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k$, so $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\le\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)=1$. The [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), which is pretty simple, also shows that the series converges.

Comment: I see so we take the absolute value of the term and if it converges, then it def converges.

Comment: Overall this was great, thanks again @Bernard

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By the *limit comparison test*, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}1/n^2/(1/(n^2-i))=1$, the series converges absolutely.

Comment: This simply means using equivalents.

Comment: @Bernard ok.  I noticed you are fond of that.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left| \frac{i^n}{n^2-i}\right|= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|i^n|}{|n^2-i|}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{|n^2-i|}$$

But we know that

$$|n^2-i|\geq ||n^2|-|i||=n^2-1$$

is true for $n\geq 2$ (this is the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality)). Then the sum becomes

$$\leq \frac{1}{|0-i|}+\frac{1}{|1-i|}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-1}<1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-n}=2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

and therefore the original sum is absolutely convergent.

Comment: sorry I changed my question, I had a typo

Comment: where did you get pi^2/6 - 1?